# greek text doesn't show in headings with cm font in memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir, greek

I have set up my document using memoir and polyglossia for hyphenation in greek and english. I have also used my own fonts, using the commands below and it worked great. I am working on sharelatex because i have collaborators.

The problem apperead when, for some reason i wanted to see how my document would look with the default font which is computer modern if i'm not mistaken. So i found the cm otf files and loaded them in my project.

The result is that i get everything ok, except for the heading of chapters, sections, subsections etc, where the greek text doesn't appear at all (only english and numbers). The funny thing is that it did appear with the other otf files i used before.

First of all, i would like to ask if this is the right way to have the deafult cm fonts, actually i want the text to have the same font as math, that's why i used cm. Secondly, if anyone can tell what is the problem with missing greek text in headings.

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathspec,xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage{url,graphicx}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Numbers = Lining,  Mapping=tex-text, BoldFont = cmunrb.otf, ItalicFont = cmunti.otf, BoldItalicFont = cmunbi.otf]{cmunrm.otf} % or other font with support for greek

\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale = MatchUppercase, Numbers = Lining, Mapping=tex-text,BoldFont = cmunrb.otf, ItalicFont = cmunti.otf, BoldItalicFont = cmunbi.otf]{cmunrm.otf} % or other font with support for english

\setmainfont[
 Ligatures=TeX,
 Numbers = Lining,
 BoldFont={cmunrb.otf},
 ItalicFont={cmunti.otf},
 BoldItalicFont={cmunbi.otf}
]{cmunrm.otf}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=arabic, variant=monotonic]{greek} 
\PolyglossiaSetup{greek}{indentfirst=false}

\setotherlanguage{english}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}

%My section styles
\setsecheadstyle{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\SingleSpacing}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\large\bfseries\SingleSpacing}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Αποτελεσματικότητα}

\section{Κοινωνική ευημερία}
\subsection{Κριτήρια ευημερίας}

\subsubsection*{Το θεώρημα του \textit{\en{Papado}}}

Υποθέτουμε ότι έχουμε δύο $A$ και ο $B$, διαφορετική κατανομή χρησιμότητας από ό,τι το αρχικό σημείο 0. Σύμφωνα με το κριτήριο του {\en \textit{Papado}}, η μετακίνηση από το αρχικό σημείο ισορροπίας
\end{document}
```

This is an example picture of my output
[image]

Comment: Quite strange, because if I set the font with `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}`, boldface Greek appears.

Comment: But don't i have to upload the fonts or a package first? If i set it just like this it puts an error saying it doesn't find cmu serif

Comment: The instruction I used chooses the font among the system ones, that's the difference.

Comment: maybe i am chosing the wrong otf files, but how can it work inside the main text?

Comment: The `cmunrb.otf` you use as bold font seems not to have greek glyph. Try `cmunbx.otf` instead (that the font use when the command of egreg is used). Btw: You are loading xunicode to early. The best is not to load it at all, fontspec will do it in the correct place anyway.